# g++ memory align in the middle of array

Tags: c++, g++, memory-alignment

Anyone have a suggestion for efficiently (memory usagage wise) performing memory-alignment on an array element OTHER than the first.  For example, let's say I have the following

```
unsigned char[516] a;
```

and I want to memory-align a[4] to a 64-byte boundary?  If, for example, the bulk of the operations happens with the last 512, for which I want SIMD vectorization, but occasionally works happens on the first 6 header bytes.

I know I could do THIS:

```
   unsigned char _a[576]  __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
   unsigned char *a = _a+60;
```

But this is a waste of 60+8 bytes (and let's assume I care about that).

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it wastes 68 bytes; it seems to waste 60 bytes. Note that `_a+60` is a constant expression and there's no good reason in the code above for the compiler to waste `sizeof(a)` bytes.

Comment: Do you have the option of storing the header information separately?

Comment: Note that even if you were to align on the first array element, it is the total size of the array that wastes memory in any case. You have 512+4 bytes, so you will waste 60 bytes at either end of the array, between any two such allocations.

Comment: Smells XY problem or extremely bad design.

Comment: @mindriot, 'seperate' header is fine, provided it is continuous (i.e. packed) with the main array.

Comment: @SergeyA please define "XY problem".  And as for the "bad design" comment, please check your assumption.  The implementation is a compression utility that uses the same memory space for raw input and compressed output.  The raw data is placed down in the array because in some rare cases, the "compressed" output ends up larger in bytes than raw input.

Comment: @user4602856 Well, that's precisely what I meant. If you can place the header in a _separate_ memory location, it's easy to keep the "relevant" data (on which you perform time-critical calculations) aligned without wasting memory. Are you sure you cannot rearrange your data? It may be worth doing so.

Comment: @user4602856 Regarding XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem